# What does the following operator - (? do something : do something) mean?

Tags: java, language-construct

What does the following code do?

```
Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
```

Comment: I did not get this question in the search query. Please clone it rather than marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`condition ? //block1 : //block2`  is the same thing as `if (condition) { //block1 } else { //block2 }`

Comment: Except the ternary operation can evaluate to something and thus be used in assignments, etc.

Comment: That's of course correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression shall be `a ? b : c`. This means: If a, then do b. Otherwise do c.

What you have here is a nested version of this syntax.